# Nunit running all tests on TestFixture even when selecting single test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, resharper

I'm running Nunit 3.5 on VS2015, Resharper Ultimate 10,

created this TestFixture

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestInfluxDbConnector
{
    [Test]
    public void TestPong()
    {
        // Arrange
        InfluxDbProxy influxDb = new InfluxDbProxy();

        // Act
        Task<bool> res = influxDb.PingAsync();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(res.Result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CreateDatabaseAsync()
    {
        // Arrange
        InfluxDbProxy influxDb = new InfluxDbProxy();

        // Act
        var databseAsync = influxDb.CreateDatabseAsync("Test");

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(databseAsync.Result);
    }
}
```

Why when I'm debugging a single Test all tests are running? (I want to debug / run only a single test)

[image]

Comment: What version of NUnit and ReSharper?

Comment: Does it do the same thing when you run the test normally?  Or only when you run it in debug?

Comment: I take it the act's are async?  So dont you need a "await" keyword or instead a .Result?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I had updated nunit 2.6.4 to nunit 3.5.0.
Try do this:

1. Disable Nunit Test Adapter in "extensions and updates".
2. Install Nunit3TestAdapter. Link:
       https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d
3. In Visual Studio use "Tests"->"Windows"->"Test Explorer" and run
   tests only from this window.

Only this way is working for me at the moment. Probably nunit 3.5 is new for Resharper and they cannot work fine at the moment.